# Add information in userInfoUri by GET

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to know how I could add GET vars in my userInfoUri, using Spring Security OAuth2.

For instance, now I have:

```
resource:
  userInfoUri: /api/user.all_info.json
```

I would like to request this kind of URI:

```
resource:
  userInfoUri: /api/user.all_info.json?access_token=XXXXX
```

If you have any ideas or tips, it will be a pleasure.

Have a nice day and thank you !